# Do a select based on the case's field value

Tags: sql, oracle

My application has created some records with undue field formatting. I need to identify the records that have case variations in the same field. Example: Field Name: "AAA bbb ccc" or Field Name: "aaa BBB CCC". Is there any way to do a select based on the case's field value?
Another specific case in name field: AAA Bbbb Cccc -> First name all in Upper case, Last name -> First Letter Upper case another letters in Lower Case

Comment: We'll need more details than this. What is the structure of your database?

Comment: What are "fields"? Tables have columns. Is this a regex question? [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check using `upper` and `lower`.

```
where upper(field_val)<>field_val and lower(field_val)<>field_val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case-sensitive regular expression to look for both upper and lower case letters:

```
where regexp_like(field, '([A-Z].*[a-z])|([a-z].*[A-Z])', 'c')
```

Comment: Excelent! How to match only this pattern "AAA Bbbb Cccc"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, you want to find "duplicates". How about this?

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2  (select 1, 'AAA bbb CCC' from dual union
  3   select 2, 'aaa bbb ccc' from dual union
  4   select 3, 'xxx yyy zzz' from dual
  5  )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where upper(col) in (select upper(col)
  9                       from test
 10                       group by upper(col)
 11                       having count(*) > 1);

        ID COL
---------- -----------
         2 aaa bbb ccc
         1 AAA bbb CCC

SQL>
```

Comment: No, I want to find how many fields have incorrectly formatted values. Correct Formatting: Aaaa Bbbb Ccc. Incorrect Formatting: AAA Bbbb Cccc

Comment: Does it mean that INITCAP values are correct? If so, that would be `where col <> initcap(col)`

Comment: @ExpertsExchange - please add this new requirement to the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select *
  from (with test (id, col) as
          (select 1, 'AAA bbb CCC' from dual union
           select 2, 'Aaa Bbb Ccc' from dual union
           select 3, 'xxx yyy zzz' from dual union
           select 2, 'aaa bbb ccC' from dual)
        select id, col, initcap(col) correct_format
          from test)
  where col != correct_format;
```

or you can also not put it in a sub-query

```
with test (id, col) as
  (select 1, 'AAA bbb CCC' from dual union
   select 2, 'Aaa Bbb Ccc' from dual union
   select 3, 'xxx yyy zzz' from dual union
   select 2, 'aaa bbb ccC' from dual)
   select id, col, initcap(col) correct_format
     from test
    where col != initcap(col);
```